# Prevent Google Keep from adding more line breaks

Tags: google-keep

When I take notes on my PC, I usually write everything down in a regular txt file first. Later, I would copy the content of that txt file over to Google Keep.

I don't know when they introduced this... "feature", but it's very irritating: whenever I paste the text from the txt file onto Google Keep, it adds another line break for every line break.

For example, this:

```
Item1
Item2
```

gets turned to this:

```
Item1

Item2
```

I know it wasn't always like this, it must've been a rather recent change. Is there a way to stop Google Keep from adding those unnecessary line breaks?

Comment: What are you using for your text editor? Did, perhaps, you change from Linux line endings to Windows line endings?

Comment: @ale It has always been plain old notepad, the regular version that comes with every Windows installation. While I'm sometimes on Windows 7, sometimes on Windows 10, it happens on both sides.

Comment: Is it the same in any browser?

Comment: @ale Only ever used Google Chrome for it. Didn't try the others.

Comment: I just tried it myself, and initially it didn't happen for me, but then I alt-tabbed away and back, and there were the extra line breaks. I don't know why it's doing that. I did find a workaround, though: choose "Show checkboxes" and then "Hide checkboxes". This seems to remove those extra line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be fixed now. Copy/paste works ok with Chrome + Google Keep, no extra newlines.

Comment: Holy crap, you're right! :O Blessed be the Google gods! Even if they are the ones who messed it up in the first place... oh well, at least it's fixed now!

Answer (score 3):

This is a well known issue of Google Keep ([one](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/1Kax_Xc2Sjo), [two](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/672mm6YoJQI), [three](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/-27iwc8cKhw), [etc](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ArdOb38hr-Q)...).

The only thing we can do is to **upvote** these tickets and wait...

There is a couple of workarounds ([one](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/672mm6YoJQI/NiHcK808CQAJ), [two](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/672mm6YoJQI/yc3bhJ2pCAAJ)) but they are not very pretty(

**UPD:**

That's fixed now!

Answer (score 3):

Use Notepad++ and change end-of-line marker to a single LF as follows:

1. Enter, or copy/paste text into Notepad++
2. Convert end-of-line markers, as follows:

   - Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix(LF)
3. Copy/paste text into Keep.

Answer (score 1):

The **best workaround** I've found is to **use Firefox** (**or Edge** in Windows 10).

Right now, the problem only seems to occur in Internet Explorer and (ironically) Google Chrome.

Other than that, I'd also recommend upvoting the tickets that Oleg Cherr provided and submitting feedback to Google Keep's development team via the "Send Feedback" link on the left pane in Keep.

Answer (score 0):

Using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) with Chrome:

```
#IfWinActive Google Keep ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
^v::
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, `r,, All
Send, ^v
return
```